How to make full transparency in Eevee 2.4.2?
I'm trying to make this shader-toon-like shader where the only parts showing are the shadow ones. But I can only get this half transparency using Ease mode on Color Ramp. Note the shadow parts aren't completely transparent

Or this weird result in Constant mode


The Shader to RGB should be plugged into the Factor of the Mix Shader. That is, if you want the shadows to dictate whether it's transparent or solid.
